# Simple sql query issue using 2 tables

Tags: sql

as i learner, i would like to learn how will be a sql statement for this condition.

I have 2 tables: Statistics and Promotions. There is no column called stats in any of the tables. Statistics has LocationID and ClickDate. Promotion has PromotionID, LocationID and CreateDate

i need Select PromotionID, stats from Promotions and Statistics ....

stats for each promotionID should be calculated as Number of columns in Statistics that has clickdate > createDate(promotion) for locationID =111 and PromotionID = 988;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What implementation of SQL?  MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: What SQL statement have you written so far?  Do you know about INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Thats sql server.. What if PromotionIDs has to come from Promotion table for each LocationID. Is that possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a start:

```
SELECT PromotionID, S.*
FROM Statistics S
INNER JOIN Promotions P on S.LocationID = P.LocationID
WHERE S.ClickDate>P.CreateDate and S.LocationID = 111 and P.PromotionID = 988
```